# Associate template to getMailer class

Tags: form, email-template

I have created a custom form, after submit send email to recipient with [JFactory::getMailer](https://docs.joomla.org/API17:JFactory::getMailer)
With this class can add body, for example:

```
$mailer = JFactory::getMailer();
$mailer->addRecipient('test-email@test.com');
$mailer->setBody('Hello world simple text');
```

In my case, my template email have many div, styles css, etc, and is pretty ugly include entire html into setBody method.
Is there an alternative?

Comment: You can just save all of the body content as a concatenated string written over multiple lines. This should help to keep things clean and readable. I'm not sure I understand the challenge.  Can you provide some sample input to give your question context?

Comment: Hi mickmackusa, yes, it's possible do this, but isn't there any more elegant solution? For example associate view file as MVC pattern?

Answer (score 1):

Within Joomla you could use `JLayout`.

```
$body = JLayoutHelper::render('path.to.layout');
$mailer->setBody($body);
```

If you have any variables you need to use in the layout, pass them as second argument:

```
$body = JLayoutHelper::render('path.to.layout', $displayData);
```

But because this is done for emails, you probably don't need `JLayout` features like template overrides. So you can use PHP's native `ob_get_contents()` to get output from PHP file. Internally `JLayout` works the same way.

```
ob_start();
include 'path/to/layout.php';
$body = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$mailer->setBody($body);
```